# is there any Framework to implement a spectrum analyzer?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios4, audio, iphone-sdk-3.0

I want to Implement the Music Tracker as like below image.

[image]

I want to implement it in to the iphone. So is there any Music API or any Sound Library available to implement it in to iPhone ??
Please help me regarding this.

Comment: FYI, this is called a spectrum analyzer.  You get this kind of output when doing an FFT on a chunk of audio samples.  There are tons of examples on how to do this on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Brad: Do you have any links to the examples you talk about, not dealing with FFT but with the actual drawing of the graph/wave? Ive been looking these past few days but I did not find anything concrete...

Comment: @Zebs, your question is about drawing boxes, rather than analyzing the signal?

Comment: @Brad, Yes, I am looking for libraries that can help me "draw the sound" after I perform FFT on it, also, if you have any good links for sound processing libraries I would greatly appreciate it, I was thinking about opening a question with a bounty to have a definitive how to on "drawing sound".

Comment: Thanks For the Valuable suggestions. I want to implement such thing.. Please see this link. And if you have any links or Source code towaeds it, then please let me know. . . link is : http://www.gearslutz.com/board/product-alerts-older-than-2-months/457617-beatdetektor-iphone-app-open-source-algorithm-bpm-detection.html

Comment: @Brad : will you please give me any link that can help me to implement it ?? or any Example Links ?? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a 'tracker', but is a visual representation of the frequency domain for a given time period during playback.

You'll need a library that can do Fast Fourier Transforms (FFT) such as [this](http://oscopeapp.com/opensource-fft-for-the-iphone).

Comment: Do you have any links for such Examples ? If you have then let me know please as i really need it. . .Thanks.

Comment: There's a link in my answer already...

Comment: Thanks, anonymous downvoter of a four-year-old accepted answer - you rock!

Comment: Thanks, anonymous downvoter of a five-year-old accepted answer - you rock!